# Retrieve original Customer object from sales_order_invoice_pay event

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm building a small module for my Magento 1.7 installation.

My function is called when the sales_order_payment_pay event is triggered.

Basically, it looks into the customer's order to check for the presence of a specific magic product.

```
 // Retrieve the order
    $order = $observer->getPayment()->getOrder();
    // Look for product ID 999, whatever that is

    try {
        $magic_product = $order->getItemById(999);


        if ($magic_product){
            // The order contains our magic product; let's find our customer object and do something with it.
            //**$customer = $order->getCustomer();**
            $customer->setData( "foo", "bar" );
            $customer->save();
        }
    }  catch ( Exception $e ) {
        // Fail silently, I don't care...
    }
```

I'm trying here to find a way to go up the object hierarchy to retrieve the customer (if any!) who made the order.

With getCustomerName() I could get it's name, but I can't find any way to find the object itself without resorting to some kind of hack. And I don't like hacks. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Geez people, if you vote down, leave a comment!

Comment: No reason to downvote. This case is special because you can't use the usual Mage::xxx(customer/session) approach due to async calling (from backend, from paypal IPN request, et cetera) ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to get the customer object that is related to the order, you have to load it and the order has the customers id:

```
$customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
// customer stuff
```

Comment: That's it! After hours working on the same thing I was completely unable to see what now seems obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$invoice = $event->getInvoice();
$order = $invoice->getOrder();
echo $order->getCustomerId();
```

Try using this in case you get a Null for Customer ID